# using mousepressed with a class

Tags: processing

I have made this soundboard which is my first project and I'm happy I got this far :)

However, I am trying to use `mousePressed` with a class and it seems to not work properly, I would like it to be able to play when clicked once and stop when click twice. at the moment, when you hover over a button on my soundboard, it will play the sound automatically until you move it to a different button.

Can anyone explain the problem to me?

```
class sound{


  float x;
  float y;

  public sound(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  } 
  void run()
  {
    draw();
    mousePressed();
  }

  void draw() {
    rect(x, y, 99, 99);
    fill(100, 10, 10);
  }
  void mousePressed(){
    if (mouseX > 1 && mouseX <  99  
    && mouseY > 1 && mouseY <  99) {
    s2.play();
    image(p7, 1, 1);
  } else {
    s2.pause();
    s2.rewind();
  }

  if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 199 
    && mouseY > 1 && mouseY < 99) {
    player.play();
    image(p9, 100, 1);
  } else {
    player.pause();
    player.rewind();
  }
  if (mouseX > 200 && mouseX <300
    && mouseY > 1 && mouseY < 99) {
    s7.play();
    image(p6, 200, 1);
  } else {
    s7.pause();
    s7.rewind();
  }

  if (mouseX > 1 && mouseX < 99
    && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 199) {
    s8.play();
    image(p8, 1, 100);
  } else {
    s8.pause();
    s8.rewind();
  }

  if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 199
    && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 199) {
    s3.play();
    image(p2, 100, 100);
  } else
  {
    s3.pause();
    s3.rewind();
  }

  if (mouseX > 200 && mouseX < 300
    && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 199) {
    s6.play();
    image(p5, 200, 100);
  } else
  {
    s6.pause();
    s6.rewind();
  }

  if (mouseX > 1 && mouseX < 99
    && mouseY > 200 && mouseY < 299) {
    s1.play();
    image(p1, 1, 200);
  } else
  {
    s1.pause();
    s1.rewind();
  }
  if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 199 
    && mouseY > 200 & mouseY < 299) {
    s4.play();
    image(p3, 100, 200);
  } else
  {
    s4.pause();
    s4.rewind();
  }
  if (mouseX> 200 && mouseX < 299
    && mouseY > 200 && mouseY < 299) {
    s5.play();
    image(p4, 200, 200);
  } else
  {
    s5.pause();
    s5.rewind();
  }

  }

}


void setup()
{
  size(300, 300);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3");
  s1 = minim.loadFile("biggie.mp3");
  s2 = minim.loadFile("crush.mp3");
  s3 = minim.loadFile("ine.mp3");
  s4 = minim.loadFile("geazy.mp3");
  s5 = minim.loadFile("lil.mp3");
  s6 = minim.loadFile("manson.mp3");
  s7 = minim.loadFile("ochoa.mp3");
  s8 = minim.loadFile("tiesto.mp3");

  soundboard =loadImage("sb.png");
  p1 = loadImage("biggie.jpg");
  p2 = loadImage("dusky.jpg");
  p3 = loadImage("geazy.jpg");
  p4 = loadImage("lil.jpg");
  p5 = loadImage("manson.JPG");
  p6 = loadImage("ochoa.jpg");
  p7 = loadImage("pvd.jpg");
  p8 = loadImage("tiesto.jpg");
  p9 = loadImage("deadmouse.jpg");
  sound1 = new sound(1, 1);
  sound2 = new sound(101, 1);
  sound3 = new sound(201, 1);
  sound4 = new sound(1, 101);
  sound5 = new sound(101, 101);
  sound6 = new sound(201, 101);
  sound7 = new sound(1, 201);
  sound8 = new sound(101, 201);
  sound9 = new sound(201, 201);
}

void draw()
{
  image(soundboard, 1, CENTER);
  sound1.run();
  sound2.run();
  sound3.run();
  sound4.run();
  sound5.run();
  sound6.run();
  sound7.run();
  sound8.run();
  sound9.run();
  sound1.mousePressed();
    sound2.mousePressed();
  sound3.mousePressed();
  sound4.mousePressed();
  sound5.mousePressed();
  sound6.mousePressed();
  sound7.mousePressed();
  sound8.mousePressed();
  sound9.mousePressed();

}

void mousePressed() {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the `mousePressed()` function of your `Sound` class from the `draw()` function of your sketch. You aren't actually checking whether the user has pressed the mouse or not.

You probably just want to move those calls into the sketch's `mousePressed()` function.

Comment: That's what i tried first, and it didnt work, I thought it would of gone smoothly as its in the class

Answer (score 0):

```
void mousePressed(){
    if (mouseX > 1 && mouseX <  99  && mouseY > 1 && mouseY <  99) {
         s2.play();
         image(p7, 1, 1);
     }else {
         s2.pause();
         s2.rewind();
       }
```

I think that here is problem, you check where is your mouse position, and if it isn't on that position sound will pause.

Comment: I understand thats the problem

Comment: I am unsure how to use mousepressed with this though. :(

Comment: You can use actionPerformed from action listner